# How to conditional format Excel 2010 to trigger flag icon in new column, based on due dates

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a row of deadline dates, I'm looking to flag with icon if deadline is past due date.  Is there a way to use conditional formatting to trigger icons?  The if then statement should be:

If Today() > "Deadline" then flag cell in column 2 with red flag icon.

Column 1
Deadline

Column 2 (Red Flag if past due date)

Comment: Whoever hit my reputation for asking this question, wtf

Comment: Do you specifically require a red flag icon, or would a small red-colored cell suffice?

Comment: WTF indeed!  Sorry, just a slip of the finger.  I had to then edit to fix.

Comment: +1 by the way, for an interesting question.

Comment: Lako, I would like to have the red flag. I did something like this, but it is not working properly: =IF((F72-10)<TODAY()<F72,0,1) and then input the conditional formatting icon setting to populate the red flag in a seperate cell.  I say it's not working because I copied down the formula, and the same date further on down the cell flags green, when the same date preceding it flags red

Answer (score 7):

I did it like this:

1st:  Added a formula to the Flag column: `=IF(A2>TODAY(),1,0)`
2nd:  Conditional formatted flags as show in picture.

[image]

3rd:  Custom format in cells to hide 1's and 0's.  The format is `;;;`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome Doug, there are still a few issues I am trying to work on, but nice work

Comment: The only issue I'm having is that it flags all future deadlines. I tried isolating it to : =IF((I3+1)>TODAY(), 1, 0)...I would need an exception to flag only deadlines one day late, but ignore dates today() plus 2 days.

Comment: Woops, although the concept was good, I can see that I got the logic backwards.  At any rate, you just need to adjust your formula.  Use nested IFs or ANDs to assign 0's to the non-flagged and 1's to the flagged.  Sorry, can't help more than that now.

Comment: =IF((I3+1)>=TODAY(),1,0), IF(I3+2)>TODAY(), 1,0)) What am I missing, this is crazy!  Whomever designed the formula logic needs their head examined.  What I wrote should work.

Comment: If you only want to flag deadlines of tomorrow: `=IF(AND(I3>TODAY(),I3<TODAY()+2),1,0)`.  If something else, just describe thoroughly and I'm sure we can get it.

Answer (score 1):

The red flag seems to be available only in the cell you are trying to format, not in an adjacent cell.

You can try that.

Select your deadline row.

Add a Conditional Formatting

Format all cells based on their values
Select Icon Sets in Format Style
Select 3 Flags in Icon Style
Tick Reverse the Icon Order
On the red flag select > enter =today() in value and Formula in type
On the orange flag select > enter =today() in value and Formula in type

You will end up with a red flag in the deadline cell if the date > today.
But unfortunately a green flag if date <= today.

Comment: I think @DougClancy 's method is better. But not possible for me on my Excel 2007. Good question by the way. +1